# Get file name from csv sent to cherrypy with jquery?

Tags: jquery, python, csv, cherrypy

I am using pandas to read .csv files I get sent over from my jquery. Users will be uploading these files to my site so I won't know the file name ahead of time. Is it possible to extract the file name at some point here in my python code? Here is my cherrypy script that reads the csv file.

```
@cherrypy.expose
def submit(self, myfile):

    cherrypy.session['myfile'] = myfile

    self.data = DataFrame(pd.read_csv(myfile.file))

    data_html = data_to_html(self.data)

    return data_html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can access the filename with `myfile.filename`. If you inspect the myfile object with `dir(myfile)`, you should see it has quite a few methods for things like this.